# Executing Shell File from Excel VBA in Mac Sonoma throws Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, shell, applescript, macos-sonoma

I am unable to execute a shell file from Excel VBA in OSX Sonoma.

Have been down a long rabbit hole and here is where I am stuck.

```
wResult = AppleScriptTask("GetData.scpt", "", "")
```

This line throws an Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Things I have tried:

- wResult is currently a variant, I have tried it as a string.
  I have tried all of the input parameters as variant and string variables.
- I have confirmed that the scpt file is in the proper directory:

  ```
  /users/Otis/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.excel
  ```
- I have confirmed that the scpt file has permissions adjusted:

  ```
  -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Otis  staff  486 Jan 27 17:34 GetData.scpt
  ```
- I have confirmed the properties of the file being called by the scpt file

  ```
  -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Otis  staff  20657 Feb 18 08:34 GetData.sh
  ```
- Script Editor and Excel have full disk access.
- Under Privacy & Security -> Accessibility Script Editor, Automator, and Excel are enabled to control the computer
- The sctp file works perfectly when called from Sript Editor and from a command line.